# Moq setting up variables inside a method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have the following method that I am trying to test, but my variables are null even if I try to set them up.

```
        public void Cancel(Guid id)
        {
            var order = _orderRepository.Find(o => o.Id == id); ** This never gets set, even with the setup below.**
            if (order == null) return;  ** Test Fails here. Returns and all assertions fails.**

            order.Status = OrderStatus.Cancelled;
            _orderRepository.Update(order);
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _orderRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository<Order>>();
            _accountServiceMock = new Mock<IAccountService>();

            _orderService = new OrderService(_accountServiceMock.Object, _orderRepositoryMock.Object);

            order = new Order()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Customer= new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Email = "test@test.com",
                    FirstName = "Tester",
                    LastName = "Test",
                    Address = "123 45 Ave",
                    City = "ABCVille",
                    PhoneNumber = "1-888-888-8888",
                    PostalCode = "T3J 0A4",
                    Province = "Super"
                },
                OrderAddons = new List<OrderAddon>(),
                Total = 363.99m,
                Status = OrderStatus.Created
            };
        }

    [Test]
    public void CancelShouldCallRepositoryWhenValid()
    {
        //var order ... (test data, in setUp)
        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        order.Id = id;

        // Repository Setup
        _orderRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Find(o => o.Id == id)).Returns(order);

        var wasOrderStatusUpdatedCorrectly = false;
        _orderRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Update(order))
            .Callback((Order o) =>
            {
                wasOrderStatusUpdatedCorrectly = o.Status == OrderStatus.Cancelled;
            });

        // Test Service
        _orderService.Cancel(id);

        // Test Assertions
        _orderRepositoryMock.Verify(x => x.Find(o => o.Id == It.IsAny<Guid>()), Times.Once);
        _orderRepositoryMock.Verify(x => x.Update(order), Times.Once);
    }
```

Is there anyway to test "var order" ? I tried SetupGet as well and didn't seem to work, Moq is new to me so forgive me in advance if this is something simple and easy.

Comment: What about `order` do you want to test?

Comment: It's not clear how you inject `_orderRepositoryMock.Object` into your service. Or do you? If it's _orderService you are trying to test, then you don't mock that, only it's dependecies. So call Cancel with actual guid, e.g. Guid.NewGuid().

Comment: I am try to test that .Find was called. The issue is when I debug the test order is always null, even if I setup the mock.

Comment: What are you setting `order.Id` to? You're mocking the `.Find` method to return an order only if `order.Id` is equal to `It.IsAny<Guid>` (which will be equivalent to `Guid.Empty` at runtime). You probably want `x.Find(o => o.Id == order.Id)` instead

Comment: I tried creating var orderId = Guid.NewGuid(); and passing that instead of It.IsAny<Guid> still null. My Find setup is never setting the order variable in the method and never reaches the Update call.

Comment: Okay, if you set `orderId` like that, you'll need to also pass that to the `Cancel` method. Also make sure `orderId` is associated with the fake order

Comment: I did. still var order is null, it like .Setup on the .Find is not working properly.

Comment: Is there any way you can set up a small example that exhibits the problem that can be run in LINQPad or dotnetfiddle?

Comment: I updated the question to include the setup

Comment: Okay, I have one new idea... Check out my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `Expression` that the repository's `Find` method expects. Try this instead:

```
_orderRepositoryMock
    .Setup(x => x.Find(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Order, bool>>>()))
    .Returns(order);
```

I'm just guessing at the type parameter for the `Expression<>`, but hopefully that helps.

Comment: Yes! One [`Expression<TDelegate>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx) instance need not be "equal to" another `Expression<TDelegate>` even if both are defined by the same arrow `o => o.Id == id`. Neither `Expression<>` or any of its base classes override the method `bool Equals(object)` as far as I can see. So the problem was that `Setup` saw an expression tree (as a sub-expression of the `Setup` expression tree) that was not "equal to" the expression tree used in the actual call. Then Moq fell back to the default behavior, which is returning `default(Order)`, i.e. `null`.